# Using jQuery UI Draggable, how to avoid drag when using scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, draggable

A long time ago I created a dialog box in my application. The dialog is pretty simple, position absolute, centered in the screen via javascript.

Now I have added jQuery UI to the application but I do not want to use jQuery UI's dialogs just because they work differently. But I did make my dialog draggable using jQuery UI as it is very easy:

```
$('#dialog').draggable();
```

There is one problem with that, some of my dialogs have scrollbars.
But using the draggable method, if there is a scrollbar, it bugs because it drags the dialog.

Is there a way for the dialog to not drag while using the scrollbar ?
I noticed there are some ways to avoid elements to be dragged, but scrollbars are not elements.

Thank you

EDIT: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FGXnR/

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle of this behavior?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As a workaround, you could try using the [`handle` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-handle) and only make the dialog draggable by the parts that aren't scrollable. (The title or some such.)

#### [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/LdEGD/1/)

Another solution that @AlexFigueiredo pointed out involves just [wrapping the content / handle in a `div`](http://jsfiddle.net/FGXnR/2/) that handles the sizing and scrolling – that seems stop the click event from being sent to the handle.

Comment: @AlexFigueiredo That's a great way to do this without the need for a title bar. It seems to work even when you simplify it down to: http://jsfiddle.net/FGXnR/1/