# jquery ui draggable accordion stick to mouse in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, google-chrome

I am working on a jquery ui website and have a draggable accordion div that experiences an odd behavior with the mouse sticking only to the scroll bars.

```
$("#item_accordion").draggable();
```

This behavior seems to only occur in Google Chrome which is stranger yet.  I can eventually get the mouse to let go of the accordion by doing a right-click and moving the mouse quickly.  I was curious if anyone have experience, and hopefully solutions, with this isse.

Thanks so much, 
Derek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same issue.  Unfortunately I don't know what's causing it since I didn't want to dig too much into JQuery but I was able to work around it by specifying a "handle" for my draggable object.  The "handle" is the only place where a drag can be initiated and since my "handle" didn't contain a scrollbar I no longer had this issue.

```
$('#overlays_dialog').draggable({handle: '.dialog-header'});
```

overlays_dialog is a div containing a child div with a class of '.dialog-header'.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793236/using-jquery-ui-draggable-how-to-avoid-drag-when-using-scrollbar